# How Insert data to database

Tags: c#, wpf

How to insert data to database when I click button Save?

> Xaml add

```
<TextBox Name="NRIC"/>
<TextBox Name="VisitorName"/>
<TextBox Name="ReasonVisit"/>
<TextBox Name="CardID"/>
<TextBox Name="CardPin"/>

<Button Content="Save" Name="SaveData"Click="SaveData_Click"/>
```

> Code behind

```
private void SaveData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = new ConnectionString();
    var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ViMS_LOCAL());
    string query = "SELECT VisitorNo,Name,NRIC,Reason,CardID,CardPin FROM dbo.[Visitor.Profile]";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        //??
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change your query. Make difference between `Insert` and `Select`

```
string query = "INSERT INTO 
                    [Visitor.Profile] (VisitorNo, Name, NRIC, Reason, CardID, CardPin)
                VALUES
                    (@VisitorNo, @Name, @NRIC, @Reason, @CardID, @CardPin)";
```

After that you need to use SqlCommand.

```
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitorNo", "Here Value for the Number in current question it is not specify from where to take it. Probably this is int or guid you should have a way to set next int or new guid");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", VisitorName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", NRIC.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", ReasonVisit.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardID", CardID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardPin", CardPin.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //do something with the exception !
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```